# when with X as () compute? and about left join

Tags: sql, join, left-join, common-table-expression

hi i have 3 questions on sql please :

1-about this simple code

```
1.    with cte as (
 2.   select * from TABLE1)

  3.  select * from cte
```

when select * from TABLE1 compute?
first the line 3 call and then line 1 then line 2
or first 1+2 and then 3?

2- when i do left/right join i have got some row with null, that make sense .

but how can i insert to the row will null "0" instead null?

to all of the row that because the left/right join get null ( if i use   inner join i will not show this row )

thanks!

Comment: am not sure what are you asking here?

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell what you're asking, but in general asking "what is the order of execution?" doesn't yield terribly meaningful answers; SQL has an optimizer that likes to move things around (sometimes, a lot), which occasionally means tables are used in a very different place than you expect.  If your query is really that simple, for example, I wouldn't be surprised if it eliminated the CTE.  Oh, and every RDBMS is different, too, so knowing yours might help.

Answer (score 1):

1. The order of execution is up to the database. The order of execution will depend on tables statistics and other factors. I've seen both order of execution.
2. If you have a NULL value and you want to show zero, use [`NVL`](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_647Tjo3PAhVHxRQKHbSZAEcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FB19306_01%2Fserver.102%2Fb14200%2Ffunctions105.htm&usg=AFQjCNH9QVTj_kFs8HoJH1pfLaTfosv5gw&sig2=GrF72tFuj-8SDrilvbte7g&bvm=bv.132479545,d.d24) for Oracle, e.g. `NVL(myColumn,0)` this will return myColumn if it's not null, otherwise 0. `ISNULL` for SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: i can't do NVL on the query
select * from Table1 left join TABLE2 on  Table1 .ID=TABLE2 .ID

how can i replace all the null that i get becuase of the leftjoin with 0?

Comment: @TOOMI19876 You can do the NVL in the `SELECT * from cte`, e.g. `SELECT id, NVL(column, 0) FROM cte`